# validating multiple textboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

```
<form name="quest" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Question</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="98">Response Type<font color="#CC0000">*</font></td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="R1" onClick="showresponse(1)"> 
        True/False
        <input type="radio" value="2" name="R1" onclick="showresponse(2)">Single 
        Best Answer
        <input type="radio" value="3" name="R1" onclick="showresponse(3)">Multiple 
        Answers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="98" valign="top"><span id="lbl" >Add Response<font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td>
      <td>
            <table border="0" width="425" cellspacing="0" id="response2" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb1" size="20" style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="R3"> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb2" size="20"  style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="2"  name="R3"> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb3" size="20" style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="3" name="R3"> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb4" size="20"  style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="4"  name="R3"> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb5" size="20"  style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="5"  name="R3"> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>   
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

I want to validate to that a person can enter min 3 responses(Add response) and max 5 responses. once enter the response only allow to select the answer(radio button). pls anbody help me . thanks in advance

Comment: Creat a jsfiddle.net and show what you have done so far. Also I would pass the radio in the call to showresponse(this) and in showresponse look at obj.value

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution below.

Note that **a full working example can be found at the end of this post**.

---

- Set the `method` method attribute of your `<form>` to `GET` or `POST`, and define its `method` attribute (= which specifies where to send the form's data)
- Add an ID to each of your "Answer" checkboxes. You can provide them the following IDs, respectively: `R1`, `R2`, `R3`, `R4`, and `R5`. Provide different names to each input.
- Disable your "Answer" checkboxes by adding the attribute `disabled`. Since you only want the responses to check / uncheck the checkboxes, we want to prevent the users from doing it.

**Eg:**

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="R1" id="R1" disabled>
```

- Add an the following events to each of your "Answer" text inputs:

  - `onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, i);"`, where `i` should be the index related to the `ID` of the checkbox concerned (check the example below). The `toggle_checkbox` function is called every time we type something inside an "Answer" textbox, and checks, or unchecks, the checkbox associated to the text input we're typing in, depending on the latter's content:

    - if the content of the texbox is empty, the function unchecks the checkbox,
    - else, it checks it.
  - `ondragstart="return false"` which prevents to copy the content from a given textbox to another.

**Eg:**

```
<td width="161">

    <input type="text" name="cb1" size="20" style="width:300px;" maxlength="100" 
        onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, 1);" ondragstart="return false"></td>

    <td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="R1" id="R1" disabled> 
    Answer
</td>
```

In the example above, `i` is equal to `1`, which is related to the concerned checkbox's ID `R1`.

- In your `<head>`, add the following JS functions:

  ```
  function toggle_checkbox(el, index) {
      var val = el.value;

      if(val!="") {
          document.getElementById("R"+index).checked = "checked";
      }
      else { 
          document.getElementById("R"+index).checked = "";
      }
  }

  function validate() {   
      var isok = false;
      var nb_checked = 0;

      for(var i =1; i<6; i++) {
          var el = document.getElementById("R"+i);

          if(el.checked) {
              nb_checked++;
          }           
      }   

      if(nb_checked < 3) {
          alert("Enter at least 3 responses!");
      }
      else {
          isok = true;
      }

      return isok;
  }
  ```

As you can see, there are two functions: one is `toggle_checkbox` and the other is `validate`.

- As explained a little bit previously, the function `toggle_checkbox` is called every time we type something inside an "Answer" textbox. This checks / unchecks the associated checkbox according to whether the content of the corresponding textbox is empty or not.
- The function `validate` is called when we submit the form. It counts the number of "Answer" checkboxes which are checked with the variable `nb_checked`. If this number is lower than `3`, then we alert the message `Enter at least 3 responses!`. Otherwise, we set the output variable `isok` to `true`, which will allow the form to be processed and sent to the link provided in the `action` attribute of the `<form>`

---

### Full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

function toggle_checkbox(el, index) {
    var val = el.value;

    if(val!="")
        document.getElementById("R"+index).checked = "checked";
    else document.getElementById("R"+index).checked = "";
}

function validate() {   
    var isok = false;
    var nb_checked = 0;

    for(var i =1; i<6; i++) {
        var el = document.getElementById("R"+i);

        if(el.checked)
            nb_checked++;

    }   

    if(nb_checked < 3) alert("Enter at least 3 responses!");
    else
        isok = true;

    return isok;
}

</script>

<head>

<body>

<form onsubmit="return validate();" method="post" action="http://www.google.com">

    <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Question</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="98">Response Type<font color="#CC0000">*</font></td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" value="1" name="Ra" onClick="showresponse(1)"> 
        True/False
        <input type="radio" value="2" name="Rb" onclick="showresponse(2)">Single 
        Best Answer
        <input type="radio" value="3" name="Rc" onclick="showresponse(3)">Multiple 
        Answers</td>
    </tr>

      <td width="98" valign="top"><span id="lbl" >Add Response<font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td>
      <td>
            <table border="0" width="425" cellspacing="0" id="response2" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb1" size="20" style="width:300px;" maxlength="100" 
                    onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, 1);" ondragstart="return false"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="R1" id="R1" disabled> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb2" size="20"  style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"
                    onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, 2);" ondragstart="return false"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="2"  name="R2" id="R2" disabled> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb3" size="20" style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"
                    onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, 3);" ondragstart="return false"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="3" name="R3" id="R3" disabled> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb4" size="20"  style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"
                    onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, 4);" ondragstart="return false"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="4"  name="R4" id="R4" disabled> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="161">
                <input type="text" name="cb5" size="20"  style="width:300px;" maxlength="100"
                    onkeyup="toggle_checkbox(this, 5);" ondragstart="return false"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="5" name="R5" id="R5" disabled> 
                Answer</td>
            </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>   
    </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PS:** Change the `action` attribute of the form. I set google's url just to let you see the redirection when the form is valid.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.